# I need to Anchored the ListView to the top, bottom, left, and right edges of the constraint layout

Tags: java, android-studio

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

    </ListView>
```

This is the list view that I have created in the XML file.
Please check whether I correctly implemented "Anchored the ListView to the top, bottom, left, and right edges of the constraint layout. "

Answer (score 0):

if you want full anchored with Constraint layout then make your ListView's Height & Weight `match_parent`

your ListView code look like this

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

    </ListView>
```

and if you want to show your listView in content size then you need to make your height and weight like below

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hardcore size make your layout Responsive-less. So, don't use hardcore size if you want to make your app responsive.